# Irreducible polynomial of every degree over finite field

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

The existence of polynomials in title has been asked as a problem on MathStack many times; some answers were *using* existence of finite bigger fields, and some answers concern Mobius function with counting argument. I didn't quickly stick to Mobius functions; so I was searching for some other proof of existence if there is.

I was thinking in the following way. To get irreducible polynomial of degree $n$, consider $n\times n$ matrices over the finite field $F$. Can't we find a special matrix whose characteristic polynomial is irreducible over $F$?

Comment: Well, a cheating answer would be the matrix representing multiplication by a generator of the multiplicative group would have this property. But finding explicit such matrices is more or less equivalent to having that polynomial (cf. companion matrix of a polynomial). I guess your question is about constructing a linear transformation in some clever way so as to guarantee that its characteritic polynomial is irreducible. I don't know how to do that.